# Linux device driver application

Tags: linux-device-driver

In my device driver I use

```
write_Parport_data(struct parport *p, unsigned char data);
```

In my application, I have to create variable of type struct parport and assign the first element to a value.
such as:

```
struct parport strApp;
strApp.base = 0x378;   // Statement 1
```

Then:

```
write_Parport_data(&strApp, 0xff);
```

gcc compiler error about statement 1

> error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct parport'

Even if I include in my application #include 
I get the same error.
Even if I use insmod, the mknod to make the driver ready, still compiling the application will give the same error. How my application should use struct parport, what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are including linux/include/linux/parport.h?  And giving the compiler the path in the compilation?  In other words, are there other instances of defining a var with the parport structure that does not get a compiler error?

Comment: I did #include <linux/parport.h> , no progress

Comment: I did, #include <parport.h> , then I replaced with , <linux/parport.h>. In the first, error: parport.h: no such file or directory. In the second case, error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct parport'.

Comment: gcc looks at usr/include/linux. There there is partport.h without any structures in. But there is usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.043/include/linux/parport.h as well as under different /arch/. Therefore how I make the compiler look at different place.

Comment: -I dir give the include paths as part of compile.  See http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Answer (score 0):

Where you have defined this structure ? You should include that header.

You should include that file which has definition of your **struct parport**

If you have defined that structure in C file, then you should extern that struct definition in header file and include that header file.